# Installing 3rd distro on my HDD

Tags: gparted

I use Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS and Linux Lite 3.0. How can I modify partitions to I can install 3rd distribution

[image]

Comment: You could shrink `/dev/sda1` (with Gparted, perhaps a Live USB / DVD, or Gparted running from the distro installed on `/dev/sda6` is necessary, since it's in use in your screenshot) in order to make space for a new partition. Is this what you mean ?

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE: Can't create more than one extended partition (thanks @ByteCommander), so creating a primary partition would still work in this case.

This would be my course of action in your case:

1. Start up a LiveUSB and open gparted. Alternatively, if your `/dev/sda6` partition is bootable and can run gparted, you can do this operation from there too.
2. Shrink `/dev/sda1` by however large you want your new installation to be.
3. Create a blank `ext4` partition in the free space you just took from `/dev/sda1`. Install to this space here.

So one thing I would suggest is creating a partition dedicated to hosting your `/home` so that you don't have to have multiple copies or links to your personal files between operating systems. This would also free up some space.

If you wanted to do that, just split the free space between an `ext4` partition for `/home` and another `ext4` for your new OS. There are other guides on Ask Ubuntu on how to move `/home` into that new partition. It is extremely helpful to do, and you keep a lot of customization and settings that you had from the other OS systems.

Comment: You must create a *primary partition* in the free unallocated space. If you want a logical volume instead, you must grow the existing extended partition (sda2) into that space first by moving its left border. Then you can create a new logical volume in there. To move the extended partition's left border, you will probably have to unmount all contained partitions first though, which means you could not do this if you have booted from sda6.

Comment: But I want modify my partitions for I can install other distro without liveusb.

Comment: @ByteCommander Can't you create more than one extended partitions (as primary)? Why must he grow the `sda2` instead of creating a new one?
@CozmaAdrianNicolae If you want to do this without LiveUSB (AFAIK...), startup the OS on `/dev/sda6` and work with gparted from there.

Comment: @Zzzach... On partitions with msdos/MBR partition table (as opposed to GPT), you may only have 4 primary partitions. If you want, you can trade exactly 1 primary partition and create an extended partition instead (so you have 3 primary + 1 extended partition). It is not allowed to have several extended partitions. There's at most one continuous extended partition, but inside that one you may have any number of logical volumes. And to modify (e.g. grow) an extended partition, none of its contained volumes may be mounted.

Comment: @ByteCommander Good to know, I never knew you were allowed only one extended partition.